# Python/Tornado - compressing static files

Tags: python, django, templates, tornado, django-compressor

For django projects there is an awesome tool called [django-compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It combines all js or css files under `compress` template tag into single cached file, like this:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/one.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">p { border:5px solid green;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/two.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
{% endcompress %}
```

I'm wondering if there is anything like this for tornado projects? Or maybe any workaround/alternative solution?

I've found [this](https://github.com/jgallen23/tornado-compress) project on github, but it's no longer maintained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [tornado_utils](https://github.com/peterbe/tornado-utils/), it should do what you want. Especially take look at [tornado_static.py](https://github.com/peterbe/tornado-utils/blob/master/tornado_utils/tornado_static.py)

> tornado_static is a module for displaying static resources in a Tornado web
>   application.
>
> It can take care of merging, compressing and giving URLs ideal renamings
>   suitable for aggressive HTTP caching.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a bit tricky to configure due to the lack of the documentation, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

The best option I've seen so far is **[WebAssets](http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)**.

> From the documentation:
>   *webassets is a general, dependency-independent library for managing
>   the assets of your web application. It can merge and compress your CSS
>   and JavaScript files, supporting a wide variety of different filters,
>   and supports working with compilers like CoffeeScript or Sass.*

You can use it in *standalone mode* with tornado (see the [specific documentation](http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generic/index.html)).

Set up is easy and pretty straightforward:

```
from webassets import Environment
static_directory = "../static"
output_directory = "/static"
my_env = Environment(static_directory, output_directory)
```

Of course you can customise it far better. The rest is pretty well explained in the documentation.

**Main features:**

- Easy integration
- Possible to compress static files in advance (command-line tool)
- Possible to compress static files on the fly
- Supports most minifying/compression libraries (JS, CSS)
- Supports LESS/SASS compiling inside the browser
- Supports compression of JS Templates inside the browser (Handlebars...)
- Supports CSS sprite mapper

Example of what a template (here, Jinja2) looks like after proper configuration:

```
# css
{% assets filters="cssmin", output="css/compiled-layout.css",
    "css/custom.css",
    "css/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
    "css/typeahead.css" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ ASSET_URL }}">
{% endassets %}

# js
{% assets filters="jsmin", output="js/lib/compiled-libs.js",
    "js/lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js",
    "js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "js/lib/bootstrap.min.js",
    "js/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
    "js/lib/d3.min.js",
    "js/lib/typeahead.bundle.min.js",
    "js/lib/moment.min.js",
    "js/lib/handlebars-v2.0.0.js",
    "js/global.js" %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}
```

I've been using WebAssets tied to Flask for a year with no hassle and it's perfectly reliable, plus well-maintained: it's been there for several years, and [last commit to date was yesterday](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets).

Comment: @alecxe Precision: I know it's a complete asset management framework and not a simple library as you asked, but I think it's quality-made and is an alternative worth digging. Tell me what you think when you have the opportunity to look further into it.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting option. I think it can be used in standalone mode with tornado. I hope I'll have time to evaluate it today - will get back to you.

Comment: I've looked through several projects that use `tornado` + `webassets` (for example, [this one](https://github.com/bashwork/speleo/tree/master/speleo.service/service)). The integration is pretty easy and transparent. Good option. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand from looking into the open-source `tornado` projects there is no standard and canonical way of doing static-files minification and compression in the "tornado world".

The different options I've seen, are:

- [`tornado_utils`](https://github.com/peterbe/tornado-utils/) (see the other answer)
- a fresh [`torminify` module](https://github.com/PaulDiakov/torminify)
- Douglas Crockford's `jsmin.c` port to python, see:

  - [jsmin.py](https://www.cacetech.com/scripts/jsmin.py)
- a Python port of the YUI CSS compressor:

  - [csscompressor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csscompressor)
  - [cssmin.py](https://github.com/lebabouin/CouchPotatoServer-develop/blob/223061ffac8f537965dd776c6bc6c492ccffe252/libs/minify/cssmin.py)
- [`slimit.minify()`](http://slimit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#let-s-minify-some-code) of the [`slimit` javascript parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit)

Only the first two options are tornado-specific. Other tools need to be tied up with Tornado template rendering and static files serving mechanisms manually.